# Como colocar os valores no topo da barra ou dentro da barra?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

```
df_x.groupby('country')['age'].median().sort_values(ascending=False).plot.bar(figsize = (16,8), color ='grey')
plt.title('Median of age players per country', pad=15, fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Age', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Country', fontsize =14)
plt.show()`
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)

Veja o exemplo abaixo

### Carregando bibliotecas

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

### Definindo gráfico

```
x = [u'col1', u'col2', u'col3']
y = [10, 17, 15]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width, color="grey")
plt.title('Exemplo')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

### Colocando valores nas barras

```
for i, v in enumerate(y):
    ax.text(i-.25, 
            v/y[i], 
            y[i], 
            fontsize=18, 
            color="black")
```

### Apresentando / salvando imagem

```
#plt.show()
plt.savefig(os.path.join('imagem.png'), dpi=300, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está funcionando no meu código ... Está aparecendo o seguinte erro: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Vc deve estar fazendo aluma coisa como `lista["alguma_string_aqui"]` ao invés de `lista[N]` onde `N` igual a um número. O que está entre colchetes é o índice ao qual o erro se reffere..

Comment: Consegui resolver esse problema, está no gráfico os valores, porém não estou conseguindo deixar na ordem certa. Será que tem algum método? O sort_values() não funciona, aparentemente.

Comment: @JoaoMoura, tem que manter a mesma ordem de `y`. Caso vc queira ordenar os valores, tem que fazê-lo antes de plotar o gráfico.

Comment: Consegui, obrigadão pela ajuda.

Comment: A minha dúvida agora é como mudar a posição dos valores. Tenho um gráfico que é um barh (barra horizontal) e os valores não ficaram bem ajustados. Como posso fazer essa modificação ?

Comment: @JoaoMoura, caso você ache que a resposta ajudou na solução do problema, favor marcá-la como solução. Minha sugestão para sua pergunta é adicionar um novo post.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, favor explicar o motivo para que eu possa melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Também não entendi esses votos negativos...